# R: Access column name within function with geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following list of plots generated with `lapply`. Within functions `subset` and `aes_string` I don't seem to have problems passing the object `i` (the column name):

```
require(ggplot2)

cols <- colnames(mtcars)
lapply(cols[2:length(cols)], 
       function(i) {
         ggplot(subset(mtcars, get(i)>0), aes_string(x=i)) +
           geom_histogram() # +
#            geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(get(i), na.rm=T)),
#                       color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)

         }
       )
```

And yet if I uncomment `geom_line` I receive the following error

```
## Error in get(i) : object 'i' not found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `xintercept` doesn't work in `aes`, so the object really doesn't exist in the environment of `geom_vline`.

You can use this as a quick fix:

```
cols <- colnames(mtcars)
lapply(cols[2:length(cols)], 
       function(i) { Mean = with(mtcars, mean(get(i), na.rm=T));
           ggplot(subset(mtcars, get(i)>0), aes_string(x=i)) +
               geom_histogram()  +
                       geom_vline(xintercept=Mean,
                                  color="red", linetype="dashed", size=1)

       }
)
```

Comment: +1 for the nice solution. I just want to add that there is something funny in the documentation here. Although `xintercept` is not listed under the aesthetics that `geom_vline` "understands", it does work if you put it in `aes` (and in fact one of the examples provided in `example(geom_vline)` uses it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aes_string` just like you did for the `x` aesthetic

```
lapply(cols[2:length(cols)], function(i) {
    ggplot(subset(mtcars, get(i)>0), aes_string(x=i)) +
        geom_histogram() +
        geom_vline(
            aes_string(xintercept = paste0("mean(", i, ", na.rm = TRUE)")),
            color = "red", linetype="dashed", size = 1)
})
```